# Symfony 2.5 deployment and cahce issues

Tags: symfony

I'm working on an old Symfony 2.5 application. I don't have SSH access on the server, I can't do the cache:clear command or any other Symfony command. I don't have access to the git repository either. I'm working with a manual backup made from the production server.

I made some changes to the Twig template, the changes are shown in DEV but in Production, the changes do not appears.

If I manually delete the /cache/prod/twig folder from the server, will it clear the cache and can it break the site.

There is also a 'deploy' file, which is a shell script, but I don't know which deployment platform has been used in the past with this file. Does someone know about this file.

Thanks

Comment: how do you access the files from production? Deleting cache/* **should** do the job to rebuild it on the next request BUT if you feel a risk you can just try it out locally?

Comment: I access the files by (insecure) FTP. I've tested on local server and changes in twig templates are applied.

Comment: i mean if you have a backup of cache/* you could delete it and if it doesnt work you restore the backup

Comment: maybe another hacky solution might be to create a controller method that can run commands for you as webs-user https://symfony.com/doc/2.7/console/command_in_controller.html

Comment: Soory for the delay. I've removed the 'app/cache/prod/twig/' folder and it works without issues. I will have a look to your controller solution, that might problably useful. Thanks